# Bootstrap typeahead and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, typeahead.js

i use of bootstrap typeahead and codeigniter two together, i want get data of two column in database and i want to search in both columns but does not display the duplicate search results. what do i do?

This is my database:

[image]

My code,

Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('typeahead/country_model');
}
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('typeahead/index');
}
public function json_search_country()
{
    $query  = $this->country_model->get();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) 
    {
        $data[] = array('id' => $value->id,
                'province' => $value->province,
                'city' => $value->province.', '.$value->city
                );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

}

Model:

```
class Country_model extends CI_Model {

    function get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('countries');
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Twitter typeahead.js Use In CodeIgniter By Baqir Memon</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- jQuery -->

    </head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Baqir Memon (BM Concepts)</h1>
                <p>Twitter typeahead.js Use In CodeIgniter</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/" target="_blank">typeahead.js</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://github.com/baqirmemon">Learn more</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
                    <legend>Twitter typeahead.js</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="country_id" id="country_id">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country_name" id="country_name" placeholder="Countries" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>



<!--https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1010-->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead-master/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(e){
        var site_url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
        var input = $("input[name=country_name]");

            $.get(site_url+'typeahead/home/json_search_country', function(data){
                        input.typeahead({
                            source: data,
                            minLength: 1,
                        });
            }, 'json');

            input.change(function(){
                var current = input.typeahead("getActive");
                $('#country_id').val(current.id);
            });

    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is JSON result:

```
[{"id":"1","province":"Aruba","city":"Aruba, ABW"},{"id":"2","province":"Afghanistan","city":"Afghanistan, AFG"},{"id":"3","province":"Angola","city":"Angola, ARU"},{"id":"4","province":"Anguilla","city":"Anguilla, AIA"},{"id":"5","province":"Albania","city":"Albania, ALB"},{"id":"6","province":"Andorra","city":"Andorra, AND"},{"id":"7","province":"Netherlands Antilles","city":"Netherlands Antilles, ANT"},{"id":"8","province":"United Arab Emirates","city":"United Arab Emirates, ARE"},{"id":"9","province":"Argentina","city":"Argentina, ARG"},{"id":"10","province":"Armenia","city":"Armenia, ARM"},{"id":"11","province":"American Samoa","city":"American Samoa, ASM"},{"id":"12","province":"Antarctica","city":"Antarctica, ATA"},{"id":"13","province":"French Southern territories","city":"French Southern territories, ATF"},{"id":"14","province":"Antigua and Barbuda","city":"Antigua and Barbuda, ATG"},{"id":"15","province":"Australia","city":"Australia, AUS"},{"id":"16","province":"Austria","city":"Austria, AUT"},{"id":"17","province":"Azerbaijan","city":"Azerbaijan, AZE"},{"id":"18","province":"Burundi","city":"Burundi, BDI"},{"id":"19","province":"Belgium","city":"Belgium, BEL"},{"id":"20","province":"Benin","city":"Benin, BEN"},{"id":"21","province":"Burkina Faso","city":"Burkina Faso, BFA"}]
```

for example i want this result after search `aru` from both together column (`province` and `city`) on database, and show me search result as following image:

[image]

Comment: i wonder the `site_url+'typeahead/home/json_search_country'` in your view is coming from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked

> i want get data of two column in database and i want to search in both columns but does not display the duplicate search results.

Thank you for sharing your code so far. However I do not get what you are doing - sorry.

Firstly, if your user is searching you begin with a search form. This form (on whatever page you want) calls a controller through the normal CI method:

```
<?php echo form_open('mycontroller/mymethod'); ?>
```

Then in that controller you collect the post data (plus any error checking you want to do).

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html

So now you have your search term. The controller that deals with the search term will load your search results view page. You can use the CI query builder to query the database which will return your results in an array, which you can display on your view page.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

When you build your query you can use 'like' terms to match your search results. For instance you might do this:

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->like('province', $search_term, 'both');
$this->db->or_like('city', $search_term, 'both');
$this->db->get('mytable');
```

The term 'both' can also be 'before' or 'after'.

You can then load the CI text helper to highlight the search phrase in your view.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html#highlight_phrase

I genuinely hope that helps and good luck with your website,

Best wishes,

Paul.

Comment: ok, so you want to search two columns, use like and or_like in the query builder. You will not get duplicate entries. You can then use the text helper to highlight the search term or do a substr on your output to replace the search term with a formatted version. That is all up to you.